# How to make toggle button border (as shown) invisible?

Tags: html, css

[image: as you can see reddish border around toggle button]

As you can see dark red border around toggle button

I use

```
.navbar-toggle
  {
   border : none;

   outline : none;
  }
```

to remove it but nothing works.

**Below given my `html` code**

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css">
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"> -->
    
    <title> Agency website </title>
</head>
<body>




  <section id="navbar">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="/logo.png" alt="website"></a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <!-- <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span> -->
    <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
     
      <!-- <i class="fas fa-tree"></i> -->
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active ">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>

      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Services</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item ">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">About Us</a>
        
       
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link " href="#">Testinmial</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link " href="#">Contact Us</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    
  </div>
</nav>
</section>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/355cdf5292.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

**Below `css` code**

```
    margin:0;
    padding:0;

}

/* navigation bar section  */
#navbar
{
    position:sticky;
    z-index:10;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right ,#9517ba ,#5f1782);     /* yaha ni chali yeh line ( doubt ) */ 
}
.navbar
{
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right ,#9517ba ,red);
    padding: 0px;

}
.navbar-brand img{

    height:50px;
    width:100px;
    /* color:blue; */
}
.navbar-nav li
{
    padding: 0 10px;
}

.navbar-nav li a
{
    color:white ! important;
    /* float: right; */
    text-align: right;
}
.fa-bars
{
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 20px !important;
}
.navbar-toggler
{
    outline:transparent;
    border-color:transparent;
    padding:0;
    background: none;
}
```

Comment: Can you show the HTML behind your button?

Comment: I think we can help you if you show your code.

Comment: Did you use bootstrap4? Navbar toggle changed .navbar-toggler.

Comment: i uploaded my HTML and CSS code , you all can check it-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set **outline: none** for **focus** state also:

```css
.navbar-toggle:focus {
    outline: none;
}

.navbar-toggle::-moz-focus-inner {
    outline: none;
}
```